# Java mysql insert jtable multiple data to mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I am trying to create a cart using jtable in java.

I know how to insert data from mysql to show on jtable.

I want to insert a product on jtable where I can select an item to void the item or change the item before saving up to database.

How can I save all the data in my jtable to database mysql?

[image: Save multiple data in table to mysql this is my question]

Comment: thank you for editing jwpfox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:
getModel() on your JTable to get Table model.

loop through the number of rows TableModel returns
and preapre insert/update statements.

Batch them together and Execute.